# Yup validation accepts values that starts with 0 without validation message

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

My form accepts value starting with 0 even if I set the minimum to 2. I know this is being parsed to a number but I need the validation message.

```
optionYear: Yup.number()
  .min(2, 'Enter between 2 to 20 years')
  .max(20, 'Enter between 2 to 20 years')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I stuck on the same issue when I worked with the Yup validation then I found the solution for it. you should try this.

```js
     optionYear: Yup.number()
              .required()
              .moreThan(0, 'optionYear should not be zero or less than zero')
              .lessThan(100, "optionYear should not be more than 2 digits"),
```

Comment: Nope. Same function as what I'm getting.

Comment: if you are using the formik with yup then you can try the touch method or handleblur event after you will validate.

Comment: can your provide an example?